# How to pass a database value from asp.net to a javascript function (slideshowpro)?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have web pages containing slideshows powered by javascript, and database connections powered by asp.net. The slideshows run flash files, whose URLs are stored in the database.

A static page would have this in the headscript:

```
> <script type="text/javascript"> var expressInstallSwfurl = {}; var
> flashvars = {}; var params = {}; var attributes = {};
> swfobject.embedSWF("/_flash/2909.swf", "slideshowdisplay", "575",
> "300", "9.0.0", expressInstallSwfurl, flashvars, { wmode:
> "transparent" }, attributes);  </script>
```

... where **/_flash/2909.swf** is the URL of the flash file for the static page, and "slideshowdisplay" is the target div.

Now I need to call the flash file dynamically, eg replacing the static 2909 with something like <%# Eval("myflashfileURL") %> to get the filename from a datasource. This fails: swfobject.embedSWF(<%# Eval("myflashfileURL") %>, ....

My javascript sucks and I'm a beginner with asp (I speak some VB, but no C#), so I'd really appreciate help with a solution that's pretty exact and complete as I'm bound to get syntaxes wrong.

Huge thanks.

Answer (score 0):

without the code to view this is all speculation. But once you make the decision to make things dynamic, you generally introduce as asp control like a GridView that contains rows of data among which is a link to the static page where the now dynamic file names are passed as parameters.

so your code would look something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    var expressInstallSwfurl = {}; 
    var flashvars = {}; 
    var params = {}; 
    var attributes = {};
    swfobject.embedSWF('<%=Request("flashfile")%>', "slideshowdisplay", "575", "300", "9.0.0", expressInstallSwfurl, flashvars, { wmode: "transparent" }, attributes);  
</script>
```

Where `"flashfile"` is parameter to the page

and to continue the example with the GridView you would have something like this (this is just a snippet):

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" >
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <a href='Your_static_page.aspx?flashfile=<%= Eval("myflashfileURL")%>'
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
     </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Mind, there are many ways to implement a dynamic solution, another would be an overlay utility like Modal or ColorBox that would allow you to bypass a call to a secondary page entirely.  It all depends on the project requirements.

Hope this gets you going in the right direction.

Comment: Many thanks fnostro. I'm not getting your javascript to work using this asp.net control to fetch the URL from the datasource:     
<asp:FormView ID="Form1" runat="server" DataSourceID="MyDatabase">
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:Label ID="flashfile" Text='<%#Eval("SlideShowURL")%>' runat="server" />
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:FormView>
-- The source code delivered to the page is  
swfobject.embedSWF('', "wideshow", "575", "300", "9.0.0",...

Any thoughts?

Comment: ..just to clarify, this is a masterpage and so I have now added to label control * ClientIDMode=static *. The page source now includes this correct-seeming id and content:
<span id="flashfile">/_flash/12345.swf</span>

Comment: It's good that you can pull the filename from the DB. That's the first step. But a label is not a link and so cannot send you to your static page. The javascript in the static page did actually work, it returned `''` which means it tried to pull in the `flashfile` parameter but found none, which is because you changed the link to a label. Also ClientID plays no part in this so setting the mode to static doesn't affect what you're trying to do.  And, a MasterPage only works when there is a child page, is the child page the static page you're talking about?

Comment: if so then that will change things a bit

Comment: Thanks. I seem to have confused you over the URL - it is the link to the flash file that appears on the final page, not a link to another page. It's a parameter of swfobject.

Comment: I wasn't able to obtain the URL parameter using your ASP expression in the javascript itself, either for the javascript argument as you had: [swfobject.embedSWF('<%=Request("flashfile")%>'] or to give a value to a variable [mySWFfile= <%=Request("flashfile")%>] that is then used for the argument. Something else I was getting wrong?

Answer (score 0):

After a few hours infuriation, here's one very ugly answer I managed to get working. It's a 'put the value in a hidden control' method.

**1**  Place an empty label control somewhere in the asp.net form, with the field that holds the URL parameter in the tooltip.

---

```
<asp:FormView ID="Form1" runat="server" DataSourceID="MyDatabase"> 
  <ItemTemplate> 
    <asp:Label ID="flashfile" 
      Tooltip='<%#Eval("myFlashFileURL")%>' 
      runat="server" 
      visible="true"
      ClientIDMode="static"/> 
  </ItemTemplate> 
</asp:FormView>
```

This returns an empty span element with the field value as the title:

```
<span id="flashfile" title="/_flash/12345.swf"></span>
```

Note that if the asp.control is hidden (visible="false") no HTML is produced, so there would be nothing for the client side javascript to read.

An empty span element seems to be a reasonable trick as it's invisible to the user, but putting backroom data in a tooltip is not good practice.

**2**  Place the script that loads the flash file AFTER the span element (eg at the end, just before the closing body tag).

**3**  Define a javascript variable, get its value from the span element, and put the variable in swfobject.embedSWF:

---

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var mySWFfile = {};
        mySWFfile = document.getElementById("flashfile").title;
        var expressInstallSwfurl = {};
        var flashvars = {};
        var params = {};
        var attributes = {};
        swfobject.embedSWF(mySWFfile, "wideshow", "575", "300", "9.0.0",
        expressInstallSwfurl, flashvars, { wmode: "transparent" }, attributes); 
</script>
```

I hate this, but it works. Page performance seems slow though.

There must be more elegant/efficient ways to do the same thing.

(I previously tried creating a variable in code-behind, thus avoiding the need for a control on the page, but I found I couldn't easily make that variable visible to the javascript, so I gave up. Maybe I should have tried harder.)

Any suggestions/comments?

Comment: Granted this is not a great solution but instead putting it in a labels tooltip you could use the HiddenField and get its value from the javascript, I cant do any examples right now as I am on my phone. Another example would be to get the data you need via AJAX and WebServices. That way you wouldnt have any rubbish controls, but it seems like overkill for your example.

Comment: OK - i see what you're doing now.  I still don't see the relationship with the master page as this all seems self contained but, as Mackwerk stated, replace the label with a hidden field and use the same premise.  Also consider using `wmode:"opaque"` to improve performance.

Comment: Thanks @Mackwerk. I'm trying to get your HiddenField approach to work. With <asp:hiddenfield id="hdnField" value='<%#Eval("myFlashFileURL")%>' the output looks good <input type="hidden" id="hdnField" value="/_flash/12345.swf" />, but in the javascript document.getElementById('hdnField') returns [object HTMLInputElement], ie the object type of the element whose id is "hdnField", but not its value. And it gets worse: "getelementByID('hdnField').value" is not recognised and ".nodevalue" returns null. What am I not doing right now?

Comment: Your very welcome.  can you update the code samples above to show the current updates?

Comment: above code samples are current; I'll add an update if/when I can get a 'hiddenfield' example to work.